# Aborting AWS S3 Uploads

Tags: java, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, abort

I have a small Java program that enables a user to Upload/Download files to/from Amazon S3.  I have a 'Cancel' button and would like to cancel the transfer once this button is pressed.

It looks like there is an `abort()` method when Downloading which seems to be working, however I am not sure how to go about aborting an Upload.  I am using a TransferManager to upload the files.  I have tried calling `transferManager.shutdownNow()` along with `transferManager.abortMultipartUploads()`, however the file still shows up in the S3 Management Console as if the transfer was not aborted.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my program, I call `transferManager.upload()` method to upload a `PutObjectRequest`object, and then it returns an `Upload` object, which contains `abort()` API. So I just call `upload.abort()` to cancel the transfer. I hope this helps.:)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you keep a queue of all your cancel requests, and once the file completes uploading to S3, you execute a delete action on that S3 object and remove that file from the cancel queue. That might be the most fool-proof way to truly "cancel" an upload.